# Cloudmade geocoding API: what are the volume limitations?

Tags: geocoding, api, cloudmade

I'm trying to understand the TOS of the Cloudmade's Geocoding API, but it's not very clear.

It [says](http://cloudmade.com/api-terms-of-service) in section 6:

> use CloudMade APIs in a manner that exceeds request volumes that are set by CloudMade in its sole discretion and published to CloudMade’s website at [www.cloudmade.com](http://www.cloudmade.com).

Unfortunately I can't find it anywhere on their website ([page](http://developers.cloudmade.com/projects/show/geocoding-http-api) on geocoding API).

Comment: Have you tried contacting them? There are email addresses on the website (on the contacts tab). We could guess, but they can tell you for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

100,000 free transactions per month then $15 per 100,00 after

http://cloudmade.com/products/geocoding

**Updated 2018**

Cloudmade discontinued the free tier.

> Tile hosting - goes hand-in-hand with the above. Whether you're using one of the standard set of in-house styles, your own custom style, or somebody else's custom style, you can point a web map library (such as Leaflet mentioned above), or an iPhone map library, at CloudMade tile servers. Your end users generate tile request traffic hitting CloudMade's servers. This service was discontinued except of paying "enterprise" users in May 1st 2014.

https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/CloudMade#Former_Products_and_Services

Answer (score 0):

Ha.  I about missed as well.  It is just print on the front of website, looks more like an ad then fine print.

http://cloudmade.com/products/map-tiles

The first 500,000 tiles is at no charge.  Then it is 25 USD for 1 million tiles.